# Access Request Object in Error Handler Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5.2 project, I have a middleware happily storing requests and responses to DB or files.
There I serialize/json_encode `$request` object for logging everything going on. (cookies, input, files, headers...)

I need to create an error handler that will use whole request object to include everything about request into the report email. But `ExceptionHandler::report()` does not accept Request as a parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel 5.2 provides [the helper method `request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-request), which works for this use case:

```
/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return void
 */
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    $request = request();

    parent::report($exception);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In App\Exceptions\Handler.php and the render method wich does have the request as parameter.
here you could fire an event to store the stuff in a session or database.

For example:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof HttpException) {
            if ($e->getStatusCode() == 403) {
                Event::fire(new UserNotAllowed($request));
                return redirect()->to("/home");
            }
            if ($e->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                if (Auth::guest()) {
                    return redirect()->to("/");
                }
            }
        }
        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {          
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        }
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

more info [here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#the-exception-handler)

Comment: _Render an exception into an HTTP response._ This is what the description says. Is that schematically right to use render for such action?

Comment: It whould be the only way you could catch the request inside your error handler.

Answer (score 1):

I try not to use helper methods and stick to pure OOP. Within `Hander` `Report` function you can use container to make the request

```php
$request = $this->container->make(Request::class);
```

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```