# Pass request to exception

Tags: laravel, exception, logging, laravel-8

Since I started logging exceptions on a production site I'm noticing a lot of them, especially 404s, more than I would expect for a site with barely any traffic, and I'd like to get to the bottom of whether they're genuine users or just bots. To help with this, I want to capture the URL that the user was trying to visit before being redirected to the 404 route, so I can keep track of which non-existent routes are being mistakenly hit. I think I'm correct in assuming this URL should be available in the request, and that I just need to store the request and pass it through to the exception.

What's the best way to do this in Laravel 8 onwards?

Comment: checkout clockwork, you can capture; ( all, except, only ) request

Comment: @silver I need to log the URL to the logfile, so not just for browser debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch `404` exceptions in `Handler(App\Exceptions\Handler)`.

If you see [Rendering Exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#rendering-exceptions)

> By default, the Laravel exception handler will convert exceptions into
> an HTTP response for you. However, you are free to register a custom
> rendering closure for exceptions of a given type. You may accomplish
> this via the renderable method of your exception handler.
>
> The closure passed to the renderable method should return an instance
> of Illuminate\Http\Response, which may be generated via the response
> helper. Laravel will deduce what type of exception the closure renders
> by examining the type-hint of the closure:

so in the register method,call `renderable`

```
public function register()
{

    $this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
            
        Log::alert("404",[
            "fullUrl"=>$request->fullUrl(),
            "path"=>$request->path(),
            "message" =>$e->getMessage()
        ]);

      return response()->view('errors.404', [], $e->getStatusCode());    
    });
}
```

Also, don't forget to import and use

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

Comment: This looks like a good start, and I would personally probably pass the request through so I can call Log on the exception view itself, but is there any way to do this this for all exceptions rather than just the ones passed through to the closure? 404s are good to log but some are a lot more critical, and I'd like to have the request info available to all of them to log when I need to.

Comment: try using  Exception instead of NotFoundHttpException

Comment: Exception gives method not found errors for `getStatusCode()`, even when conditionally checking for it. Is there a base class for all exceptions that also knows about `getStatusCode()`?

Comment: you will get status code in  $e->getCode() or you have to use HttpException

Comment: I've been experimenting with HttpException for the last few hours but it doesn't include every other exception, so I needed something more higher-level like Exception. `getCode()` does exist on Exception but always seems to return 0 no matter what, for both exceptions and HTTP errors.

Comment: @HashimAziz i think while throwing exception status code not passed so it taking default as zero

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** just a few hours of using this solution in production, with the benefit of the newly-added request URLs, has confirmed for me just how many of these HTTP 4xx errors are junk - mostly automated bots and maybe a few script kiddies trying common routes. For this reason I've added some logic to ignore 404 and 405 errors, and may still add others that mostly contribute noise to the logfile.

---

This was harder than it should have been, but this is the solution I'm currently using to log the request with *all* exceptions. It's probably not the cleanest way to do it, but it works perfectly for my needs. Thanks to John Lobo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75413387/1191147) for pointing me in the right direction.

It works by inspecting each instance of the Exception class and using PHP's `instanceof` to check whether it's a HTTP exception or not. If it is, it gets logged with the request URL and returns a view with a status code. If it's a generic non-HTTP exception, it gets logged with the request URL and returns another view with no status code (or you can keep the default exception behaviour by removing the return block, which renders a blank screen in production).

```
public function register()
{

$this->renderable(function (Exception $exception, $request) {

  $url = $request->fullUrl();

  if ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
  
  $status = $exception->getStatusCode();

  // Do not log HTTP 404 and 405s errors for reasons that will 
  // become apparent after a few hours of logging 404s and 405s
  if(($status !== 404) && ($status !== 405)) {
    Log::warning("Error $status occurred when trying to visit $url. Received the following message: " . $exception->getMessage()); 
  }

  return response()->view("errors.error", [
  "exception" => $exception,
  "status" => $status
  ],
  $status
  );

} else {

  $status = $exception->getCode();

  Log::warning("Exception $status occurred when trying to visit $url. Received the following message: " . $exception->getMessage()); 

  return response()->view("errors.exception", [
  "exception" => $exception,
  "status" => $status

  ]);
  }
});

// Optionally suppress all Laravel's default logging for exceptions, so only your own logs go to the logfile 
$this->reportable(function (Exception $e) {
})->stop();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out a *much* simpler way to do this, so simple I should be kicking myself - courtesy to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959941/1191147) for pointing it out. Although that answer uses it in Illuminate's upstream implementation of the exception handler, you can simply use it directly in `app\Exceptions\Handler`'s `reportable()` function:

```
  $this->reportable(function (Exception $exception) {
    
    $request = request();

    // Use $request as needed here

    parent::report($exception);

  });
  }
```

This will pass the request to all logging.